# ReactJS inline editing

Tags: reactjs, redux

what i am trying to do is when the user selects one of the options from a drop-down, the selected option should be displayed in a panel below. When displaying the selection certain parts/words should be replaced with text fields.

[image]

It should then display '**wait for** *text-field* **to contain text** *text-field*'. So that the user would be able to enter what the ElementKey and ExpectedText values should be.

What i've tried to do so far is, through string manipulations find out where the the tags are and replace them with text-fields.

```
displayInputBox = (event, str) => {
    let strArr = str.split(" ");
    let newArr = [];
    let newStr = "<div> </div>";
    console.log(strArr);
    for (var i = 0, tot = strArr.length; i < tot; i++) {

        if (strArr[i].includes("<")) {
            newArr.push(<FormControl type="text" placeholder={strArr[i]} />);

        } else {
            newArr.push(strArr[i]);
        }
    }
    return (newArr);
}
```

This works but when printing an array we need to give unique IDs as well.

I understand that is not an efficient solution, is there any other efficient approach i could try?

I am also using Redux, but i do not want to maintain states for individual text field values.

Are there any libraries like react-inline-edit which could help me here?

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please insert your code as text, not screenshot.

Comment: I see no problem with using ID's !! just add the attribute Key and fill it with the incremental variable i in your for loop, Key's don't require unique ID's over the whole application, it only require them in the current incremented element.

Comment: Also you can distract your array inside a div element if you don't what to add keys, you can use the new Fragment API, you have many options

Answer (score 3):

I think this is something that your are looking for, sorry for styling but anyway. So the idea is to separate editable option into separate component (`Editable`). It may look like below:

```
const Editable = ({text, field, value, onFieldChange, onValueChange}) => (
  <div>
    {text[0]}
    <input name="field" type="text" value={field} onChange={onFieldChange}/>
    {text[1]}
    <input name="value" type="text" value={value} onChange={onValueChange}/>
  </div>
)
```

And pass props to it from your `Option` component:

```
class Option extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: ['wait for ', ' to contain text '],
        isEditable: true,
        field: 'text-key',
        value: 'text-value'
    }

    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this)
  }

  onEdit(e){
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
  }

  render(){
    const {field, value, text} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isEditable
          && <Editable
              text={text}
              field={field}
              value={value}
              onFieldChange={this.onEdit}
              onValueChange={this.onEdit}
            />
        }
        {!this.state.isEditable && <div>Key: {this.state.field} Value: {this.state.value}</div>}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({isEditable: !this.state.isEditable})}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Worked example you can find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/95573/). Hope it will help you

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this! Your fiddle example was quite helpful. But since I cant have separate states, i was not able to use it exactly.